# Simple Big-O calculation

Tags: big-o

I am aware intuitively that two for loops make an O(n^2) function, but what if the loops are unrelated.  How is it expressed

For example:

```
for(x = 1; x < t; x++)
    for(y = 1; y < z; y++)
            do something trivial
    end
end
```

is the big-o of this O(t*z)?  or is it O(n^2) or is it O(t^2).  I have always overlooked this, but I would like to know now.

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's O(t*z). If you have two nested loop each doing n iterations you have n^2 because of n*n :)

It's like computing the area.. for every t you iterate z times.. so it's intuitively t*z..

Or you can imagine to have a counter inside the loops.. how much will be the result?

Answer (score 1):

Basically it's really O(t*z), but unless there is something specific about the problem otherwise, you would normally just say O(n^2).  The reasoning for that is pretty simple: assume you have t,z with t≠z.  Then for any particular t,z there exists t/z which is a constant.  You can factor that out, it becomes a constant in the expression, and you have n^2.  O(n^2) is the same as O(t^2) for our purposes -- it's a bit more correct to say O(t^2) but most people would understand you using the generic n.

**Update**

Okay, sorry, let's take this a bit further.  We're given t,z, both positive natural numbers with t≠z, and with no specific functional relationship between t and z.  (Yes, there *could be* such a relationship, but it's not in the problem statement.  If we can't make that assumption, then the problem can't be answered: consider, eg, that *z* = *t<sup>x</sup>*.  We don't know the *x*, so we can't ever say what the run time would be.  Consider *z* = s<sup>t</sup>.  If I can assert a functional relation *might* exist, then the answer is indeterminate.)

Now, by examination we can see it's going to be O(t*z).  Call the function that's the real run time *f(n)=n<sup>2</sup>*. By definition, *O(f(tz))* means the run time *f(tz)* ≤ *kg(tz)* for some constant k>0.  Divide by z.  Then *f(t)/z* ≤ *(k/z)g(t)*, and thus *f(t)* ≤ *kg(t)*.  We substitute and get *f(t)=t<sup>2</sup>* and renaming the variable makes that *O(n<sup>2</sup>)*.

Comment: What do you mean by "unless there is something specific about the problem otherwise"? I'd say that it is correct to say `O(n^2)` if and only if `t` and `z` are both bounded by `n`.

Comment: @sepp2k, exhibit a pair of t and z which are both fixed and which aren't bounded by some constant n.

Comment: what? "let's say we have O(n^2) and a constant n => so we get O(1)". not really an argument? do I misunderstand something? why should anything be fixed?

Comment: This whole answer is very confusing to me. Let's consider for example the scenario where `t` is the number of nodes in a graph and `z` the number of edges. Without any further restrictions on the graph that means that `z` is at most `t^2`, so you could say that the algorithm is in `O(t * t^2) = O(t^3)` (or `O(n^3)` if you want), but you could definitely not say that is in `O(n^2)`.

Comment: @Charlie: If `t` and `z` are both fixed, the whole thing is `O(1)`.

Comment: @sepp2k On the first question, the existence of a functional relationship between t and z is exactly the special condition I mentioned.  On your second point, go back and rethink that.

Comment: Okay, I didn't really get what you meant by "unless there is something specific about the problem" until now. Fair enough. Regarding `t` and `z` being fixed: I've thought again and again and it still means that the whole thing is `O(1)`.

Comment: @sepp2k Okay, what does "fixed" mean to you? I'm saying "exhibit a pair of t and z which have definite values for which you can't do the algebra in the update."

Answer (score 1):

```
for(x = 1; x < t; x++)
    for(y = 1; y < z; y++)
            do something trivial
    end
end
```

As written, these loops execute `(t-1)*(z-1) = t*z - t - z + 1 times -> O(t*z)`

Answer (score 0):

Normally two for loops inside one another is O(n^2) which is read `O n squared`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know that I would consider this O(n^2) without some further information about the how the loop will be used.

If z will always be less than or equal to 1, you would get O(n) or O(1).